# Xcode 11 fonts issue (react-native)

Tags: xcode, react-native, fonts

After xcode upd to v.11 (before update all works fine) Custom fonts do not work

But fonts are displayed in xcode

react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'], };
```

react-native link - did not help

cleaning derived data and build folder - did not help

Answer (score 0):

So it seems problems with font itself with new versions of xcode or ios. Even on new and fresh project - it does not work. 
Other custom fonts - work fine. Sp I found similar font

But before update - it worked